# Using ANTLR with Python with code migrated from Java

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, parse-tree

I have the following grammar and I want to parse inputs to get associated ASTs. Everything is easy with ANTLR for Java. Since ANTLR4, in grammar files, you don't have to specify options `output=AST; to get ASTs information.

**Hello.g**

```
grammar  Hello; //  Define  a  grammar  called  Hello
stat    :   expr NEWLINE       
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE 
    |   NEWLINE   
        | expr
    ;

expr:   atom (op atom)* ;

op  : '+'|'-' ;

atom    :   INT |   ID;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;

INT :  [0-9]+ ;

NEWLINE :   '\r' ? '\n' ;

WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

**Test.java**

```
import  org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import  org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import java.io.*;
import lib.HelloLexer;
import lib.HelloParser;
public class Test {
    public  static  void  main(String[]  args)  throws  Exception  {
        ANTLRInputStream  input  =  new  ANTLRInputStream("5 + 3");
        //  create  a  lexer  that  feeds  off  of  input  CharStream
        HelloLexer  lexer  =  new  HelloLexer(input);
        //  create  a  buffer  of  tokens  pulled  from  the  lexer
        CommonTokenStream  tokens  =  new  CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        //  create  a  parser  that  feeds  off  the  tokens  buffer
        HelloParser  parser  =  new  HelloParser(tokens);
        ParseTree  tree  =  parser.expr();  //  begin  parsing  at  init  rule
        //System.out(tree.toStringTree(parser));  //  print  LISP-style  tree
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
    }   
}
```

**The output will be:**

```
(expr (atom 5) (op +) (atom 3))
```

**But would you please tell me how to obtain the same result with Python implementation?** Currently, I'm using ANTLR 3.1.3 Runtime for Python. The following code only returns "(+ 5 3)"

**Test.py**

```
import sys
import antlr3
import antlr3.tree
from antlr3.tree import Tree
from HelloLexer import *
from HelloParser import *

char_stream = antlr3.ANTLRStringStream('5 + 3')
lexer = ExprLexer(char_stream)
tokens = antlr3.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = ExprParser(tokens)
r = parser.stat()

print r.tree.toStringTree()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an antlr4 runtime for Python now (https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Python+Target) but toStringTree is a class method in the Python runtimes. You can call it like this to get the lisp style parse tree including stringified tokens:

```
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.tree.Trees import Trees
# import your parser & lexer here

# setup your lexer, stream, parser and tree like normal

print(Trees.toStringTree(tree, None, parser))

# the None is an optional rule names list
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no Python target for ANTLR 4, and ANTLR 3 did not support the automatic generation of parse trees to produce the output you are looking at.

You might be able to use the AST creation functionality in ANTLR 3 to produce a tree, but it will not have the same form (and certainly not the simplicity) of ANTLR 4.